# Пересортировка данных при запросе на linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

При запросе на сервер Oracle через Oracle Provider for OLE DB (включен интерпроцессинг) результат запроса возвращается вперемешку (значения из **clob**).

- На разных версиях Oracle 12,19,20
- На разных версиях SQL Server и серверах
- C OpenQuery и без него
- Версия Oracle 12

Напрямую (sql developer) таких проблем нет

Comment: SELECT ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,IDMAIN,COMMENT
FROM [LSTL2]..[DIR].[MAINDATA] t where
t.enddate >= DATEADD(hour, -3, (cast(floor(cast( GETDATE()-1 as float)) as datetime))) and
t.enddate < DATEADD(hour, -3, (cast(floor(cast( GETDATE() as float)) as datetime)))

Answer (score 1):

У существующего подхода есть две проблемы:

- Весь набор данных переносится из Oracle в SQL Server как есть.
- Фильтр предложения WHERE применяется на стороне SQL Server.

Лучший способ — использовать другой метод: `EXECUTE ... AT [Linked Server]`

Этот метод заставляет выполнять `SELECT ...` на стороне Oracle, а также даже передавать параметры для Oracle.

Вам придется изменить параметры @start и @end, поскольку Oracle ожидает их в формате, отличном от формата SQL Server. Вы можете протестировать формат параметров непосредственно со стороны Oracle. Возможно, используйте функцию Oracle `to_date()`.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, -3, (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)));
DECLARE @end DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, -3, (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)));

EXECUTE(N'SELECT ID,
       STARTDATE,
       ENDDATE,
       IDMAIN,
       COMMENT
FROM [DIR].[MAINDATA]
WHERE enddate >= ? AND enddate < ?
ORDER BY ...',
@start, @end) AT [LSTL2];
```

Comment: да, идея отличная, особенно с параметрами, но проблему не решает, к сожалению. заметил, что если указывать ID в IN ('12',13'','14','15') ничего не путается, другие сортировки также безрезультатны.

Comment: Вы можете добавить предложение `ORDER BY ...`. Oracle отсортирует набор данных в соответствии с вашими потребностями. В противном случае модель данных базы данных основана на неупорядоченном множестве (unordered set).

Comment: наверное unordered set, потому что order, разумеется, в первую очередь пробовал.
интересно, что если перечислять в where id in ('1','2') результат корректный, но стоит указать where id in (select id from <выборка>) снова вразброс.

Comment: Итак, вы пытались добавить предложение ORDER BY ...? Как это показано в ответе.